# Transpose each row in SQL SELECT

Tags: sql, pivot, transpose, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The following SQL

```
SELECT concat('CSE_', course_code), concat('CS_', course_code)
FROM classes
```

this returns some like this:

```
CSE_210   CS_210
CSE_570   CS_570
CSE_480   CS_480
```

Instead I need

```
CSE_270
CS_270
CSE_570
CS_570
CSE_480
CS_480
```

i.e. each row transposed. exactly in that order.

What is the best way to implement this using just SQL?

Comment: Please post some sample data to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest method is `union all`:

```
SELECT concat('CSE_', course_code)
FROM classes
UNION ALL
SELECT concat('CS_', course_code)
FROM classes;
```

However, it is more efficient typically to use a `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT concat(v.prefix, c.course_code)
FROM classes c CROSS JOIN
     (VALUES ('CSE_', 1), ('CS_', 2)) v(prefix, ord)
ORDER BY c.course_code, v.ord;
```

Comment: Gordon, neither of these will output in the order that I need. Please see my question.

Comment: @SaqibAli . . . It is not clear from your question that the ordering is important.  I added an `order by` to the second solution.